# median_absolute_deviation of 2D array throws AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

The chunk of code is:

```py
import scipy as sp 
import numpy as np

print(temps.shape)
print(temps.ndim)
mad = sp.stats.median_absolute_deviation(temps, axis=1, nan_policy='omit')
med = np.median(temps, axis=1)
mean = np.mean(temps,axis=1)
```

`temps.shape` is (992,2048) and `temps.ndim` is 2

but line 3 using `median_absolute_deviation` throws `AxisError`: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1. If I comment out the line, `med` and `mean` run fine with no axis error. Why is this happening and how do I get it to compute the median absolute deviation along the axis of length 2048?

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?   You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have your exact array, but I have tried replicating your code to produce your error:

```
from scipy.stats import median_absolute_deviation
import numpy as np

# mimicking your data with random numbers
temps = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, size=(992,2048))
# setting values of axis 1 to NaN
temps[:,1] = np.nan

print(temps.shape)
print(temps.ndim)
mad = median_absolute_deviation(temps, axis=1, nan_policy='omit')
med = np.median(temps, axis=1)
mean = np.mean(temps,axis=1)
```

With the argument `nan_policy='omit'` in `median_absolute_deviation()` you are effectively asking the function to remove all the `np.nan` values from the array `temps`.

As I have shown above, if there is an entire column of these values, they are removed by calling `nan_policy='omit'` and so the array `temps` is reduced to an array of dimension 1 and the errors you see arise.